# How do you call a Variable from another method in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just started coding for fun again and I ran into some trouble. I want to create a simple calculator where the user inputs the numbers and the program does the addition or subtraction for it.I'm trying to use a method for cleaner code but I kept getting errors. Here is the code below:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:" + " " + "'press enter'");
        int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
        int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Add" + " " + " Subtract" + " " + "Are your only two options.");
        string UserOperations = Console.ReadLine();
        if (UserOperations == "Add" || UserOperations == "+")
        {
            AddMethod();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (UserOperations == "Subtract" || UserOperations == "-")
        {
            SubtractionMethods();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public static void AddMethod(int number1, int number2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number1 + number2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you include the details of the errors you are getting?

Comment: `"How do you call a Variable from another method in C#?"` ← Pass the value to the method as a parameter or as an argument so other way. Or have the containing type have some state where the value is stored.

Comment: "...but I kept getting errors" ← When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to include that error. An error that occurs at runtime this case its called an `Exception` (*this is how errors manifest themselves in .net*). Include the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down. Use the  [edit] link on your question to include that detail, *do not* include it as a comment. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ... or change `public static void AddMethod(...)` to `public static int AddMethod(...)` and `return number1 + number2;` from it

Comment: Your AddMethod Expects two integers as parameters. You should call it like this:  AddMethod(number1, number2);

Answer (score 3):

```
AddMethod(number1, number2);
```

You declared `number1` and `number2` above in the code block.